# How can I say that I have used a piece of cloth a lot?

Tags: verbs

What is the best way to say that you have used a piece of cloth a lot?

Does it sound OK to say:

> I have worn this dress a lot.

Comment: It's fine to say that, but I wouldn't call a garment a 'piece of cloth'. That suggests a cloth that you have used for cleaning things.

Comment: I think you mean the word **clothes** as in "some clothes". It's one of those English words that doesn't have a singular form e.g *scissors*, *trousers* etc. You nearly got it right by saying  "a piece of *cloth*, it should have been **clothing**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum